# how to allow electron app to listen to incoming traffic on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder

I am creating a TCP server to listen data from a IOT client in Electron.
In mac I get pop up about allowing incoming traffic in app but in windows nothing happens and windows does not allow incoming traffic when firewall is on.
but if I turn off the fire all app works fine. But I want app to work even if firewall is on
can anyone help so that I can add exception to firewall using nodeJS code in my electron app?

```
function startSocket() {
  try {
    dataServer = net.createServer();
    dataServer.on("error", function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      showMsg(error.message, "red");
      dataServer.close();
    });
    dataServer.on("connection", handleConnection);
    dataServer.listen(port, function () {
      const address = dataServer.address();
      var privateIP = ip.address();
      sendMessage({
        title: "start",
        frequencies: frequencies,
        Ns: Ns,
        count: frequencies.length,
        ip: privateIP,
        port: port,
        singleChannel: singleChannel,
      });
      disableElements([startBtn]);
      noLostPackets = 0;
      console.log(`Listing for Data at ${privateIP}:${address.port}`);
      showMsg(`Listing for Data at ${privateIP}:${address.port}`, "green");
    });
    function handleConnection(conn) {
      let fullDataString = "";
      var remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ":" + conn.remotePort;
      showMsg(`new client connection from ${remoteAddress}`);
      conn.on("data", onConnData);
      conn.on("end", onConnClose);
      conn.on("error", onConnError);
      function onConnData(data) {
        fullDataString += data.toString();
        //appending data to the file
        showMsg(`Packet recived`);
        conn.write("data recived");
      }
      function onConnClose() {
        showMsg(`writing to file...`);
        packet.classList.add("packet");
        restartAnimation();
        try {
          data_obj = JSON.parse(fullDataString);
        } catch (error) {
          showMsg("Not Valid JSON data", "red");
          console.log("Not Valid JSON data");
          return;
        }
        let numberOfLines = data_obj.data.split(/\n/).length - 1;
        writeToFile(
          saveFilePath,
          data_obj.data,
          data_obj.frequency,
          numberOfLines
        );
        noOfPackets += numberOfLines;
        bigNumber.innerText = noOfPackets;
      }
      function onConnError(err) {
        console.log(err);
        showMsg(`Reconnecting...`, "green");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    showMsg(error.message, "red");
  }
}
```

Comment: You could be hitting a constraint where an app is not allowed to create a listening socket when not run on elevated permissions. Try to "run as administrator" and when it works, just create an [app manifest that makes sure users run your app with elevated permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/604927/how-do-i-configure-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-automatically). Drop a note if this helps.

Comment: I tried running app as a admin but still same problem.
Antivirus firewall is blocking app for incoming traffic.

Comment: What port number it listens on?

Comment: port number 8888

Comment: (sorry, deleted previous comment by accident). You should be able to [add firewall rule programmatically](https://winaero.com/open-port-windows-firewall-windows-10/) (scroll down to the commandline/powershell section)

Comment: I found out that I can add firewall rule by creating a child process in node.
but my app do not have any problem with default windows firewall.
there are some antivirus firewall which are blocking the connection

Comment: I am afraid you possibly cant do anything about an external software blocking your app.

Comment: I will try code signing with my app. I am hoping that then antivirus will not block incoming traffic for my app

Comment: Drop a note if this helps so that someone possibly learns from your case.